# Inheritance: Cast (Child-)UserControl to the layout of its Base

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, user-controls

Sorry for the somewhat strange title. Let me sketch the situation:

I have a `general usercontrol` named TrafficInfraction.
2 other user controls `inherit` from this TrafficInfraction. Let call them Speeding & Parking. De scheme looks as follows:

```
TrafficInfraction
      Speeding (Inherits from TrafficInfraction + Has 2 extra buttons)
      Parking (Inherits from TrafficInfraction + Has 1 extra textbox & 1 extra button)
```

Add runtime I would like to `cast` the `Speeding/Parking` usercontrols to usercontrols of the type `TrafficInfraction` (on a specified form, i don't need the extra controls).

I know its possible using a shallow copy as follows (`fIntractions` is a `flowlayoutpanel`):

**Note**: *currTrafficInfractions is a collection `(List Of)` of TrafficInfraction. It can contain the oridinary trafficInfraction & user controls inheriting from trafficInfraction: Speeding ,Parking, .... (possible further derived usercontrols). currTrafficInfractions is filled based on property defined on the base-Control(TrafficInfraction). The property is named 'Fine' and is a `double`. All the user-controls with a Fine larger then 100 (for instance) are added to the list.*

```
        For Each infra As TrafficInfraction In currTrafficInfractions
            fInfractions.Controls.Add(infra.Clone())
        Next
```

Yet i don't want a shallow copy (As i lose certain properties apparently: tooltips,... ) and want the object itself. So i assumed it would work like this:

```
        For Each infra As TrafficInfraction In currTrafficInfractions
            fInfractions.Controls.Add(Ctype(infra,TrafficInfraction))
        Next
```

or

```
        For Each infra As TrafficInfraction In currTrafficInfractions
            fInfractions.Controls.Add(infra)
        Next
```

But i was proven wrong. The layout doesn't alter (unlike the effect of `.Clone`). I still see those extra controls. Simply hiding them wouldn't work. As the location of the controls (inherited from TrafficInfraction) are different on Speeding & Parking.

**Question:** How can i cast/convert an usercontrol to the layout of its base-usercontrol. And display it correctly as `TrafficInfraction` to the User (without the extra controls declared in `Speeding` or `Parking`)?

**Note:** `TrafficInfraction` implements `IClonable` . This is probably the reason why `.Clone` offers some success.

Comment: what is `currTrafficInfractions`?

Comment: updated the questions: currTrafficInfractions is a collection of Trafficinfractions.

Comment: owned and filled by whom?

Comment: show the specific type for it; what KIND of collection?  Is it a `List(Of traffics)` or a `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` of them?

Comment: Sorry: its a 'List(Of )'. (will update the 'note' with some extra info soon!

Comment: what does `But i was proven wrong` mean? do you get an error message?  NET clearly sees the children as being a valid TrafficInfraction type or it would not allow it in the List<T>

Comment: The usercontrol aren't cast to the base-control. The layout stays the same. I want the layout to change to that of the base-control.

Comment: I think if you add `console.WriteLine(infra.Name)` to the For Each loop, you'll see they are being iterated. (I assume "base control" means the flow panel)  I dont understand why you want to make copies of these things, if they are in a List, the second For/Each should work - are you sure it is flow panel and not a tablelayoutpanel?

Comment: I guess i wasn't quite clear (Sorry :( ): Could you read the 'Note' in the question. The "base control" is the type ´TraficInfraction´ & the 'Sub'-controls are ´Speeding´and ´Parking´. I want to achieve the same layout (for the overviewpanel), the layout should be that of 'TrafficInfraction'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting (`CType`) and cloning will not change the type of the object, just the type of the reference to it, which is why you are still seeing the subclass layout.  You will have to create a [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx) (the article is for C#, but applies to VB.NET too) on your base class `TrafficInfraction`.

```
Public Class TrafficInfraction
    Public Sub New(copy As TrafficInfraction)
       Me.SomeProperty = copy.SomeProperty
       Me.OtherProperty = copy.OtherProperty
       etc.
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then use that:

```
For Each infra As TrafficInfraction In currTrafficInfractions
    fInfractions.Controls.Add(new TrafficInfration(infra))
Next
```

**Update**

As discussed in the comments, this answer is not entirely correct - `Clone` implemented only on the base class will work just as well as a copy constructor for copying a subclass instance to a new base class instance.

Comment: Yet '.Clone' does partially work.  It only refuses to copy/clone some basic properties (Tooltips, ...) . I knew i could do a deep-copy, yet i'm fearfull about the performance-impact it may have.

Comment: @svranken Hmm, I just checked the docs, and it doesn't look like `UserControl` is `ICloneable`, so is that implemented on your `TrafficInfraction` class?

Comment: That is correct. I forgot to mention that in the question. I'll add it soon (+ 1 though for the effort!)

Comment: Oh darn it, I see the solution now in front of me! if i modify the "Clone" method in the 'Sub'-Controls, then i can reach the desired result. Thnx Man!

Comment: @svranken Maybe I got lost again! :-) I would think what you want is to only implement `Clone` in the base class, so that calling `Clone` on a subclass - e.g. `aParking.Clone()` would return a new `TrafficInfraction`.

Comment: Well i changed the logic somewhat. Right now it makes more sense to implement it in sub-controls ( with a  vision to the future & other infractions).